# Postback issue after adding jquery.blockUI to aspx

Tags: asp.net, postback, jquery-blockui

The button on the page is not doing a postback after I add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" />
```

to the header of the aspx page. If I comment this line out it works. I do have the jquery.blockUI.js at that location. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have self-closing `<script>` tags...you'll get some odd behavior and missing files you *think* are being loaded.  Your tag should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```